# git clone not downloading lfs files in submodule under Linux but Windows

Tags: linux, windows, git, gitlab, git-lfs

I have several projects which are split in separate repositories each using LFS to
store large binary files and the main repository is referencing other repos as submodule:

```
MAIN_REPOSITORY
|
+-OTHER_REPOSITORY (as SUBMODULE)
```

If I clone the main repository like this:

```
git clone --recurse-submodules https://gitlab.com/MyUser/MainRepo.git
```

it works fine under Windows (all LFS files downloaded) but fails under Linux:
Under Linux the LFS files in the main repo are downloaded correctly but the LFS files
in the submodule are just the small files used as pointer to the LFS storage.

The issue is very similar to this topic:
[git clone lfs files not fully downloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65363299/git-clone-lfs-files-not-fully-downloading)

and the solution given there also works in my case:

```
git lfs clone --recurse-submodules https://gitlab.com/MyUser/MainRepo.git
```

However as 'git lfs clone' gives me a WARNING:

```
WARNING: 'git lfs clone' is deprecated and will not be updated
      with new flags from 'git clone'

'git clone' has been updated in upstream Git to have comparable
speeds to 'git lfs clone'.
```

I wonder how to do it correctly and I'd like to understand why it works
under Windows but not under Linux.

Comment: Have you run `git lfs install` for your user at least once on this machine?

Comment: Yes. This was the first thing I ensured. But wouldn't the main repo also omit the LFS files if this install is missing?

Comment: `git lfs clone` will probably set it up for you in the main repo if you haven't already.  Also, Git for Windows always sets the configuration up upon install.

Comment: The question is: How can I checkout the files in repository? If I do 'git lfs pull' I get the them - but marked as modified. Anyway I'd expect a consistent behavior on Windows and Linux for this use-case.